# System of quadratic equation with three variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, quadratics

Let $x, y, z$ be real numbers such that :

$$x^2+ xy+ yz+ zx = 30$$
$$y^2+ xy+ yz+ zx = 15$$
$$z^2+ xy+ yz+ zx = 18$$ ,

then:  $$x^2+ y^2+ z^2 = ......$$.

Answer (score 1):

It's $$(x+y)(x+z)=30,$$
$$(x+y)(y+z)=15$$ and
$$(x+z)(z+y)=18,$$
which gives $$(x+y)^2(x+z)^2(y+z)^2=8100.$$

Now, we have two cases:

1. $$(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)=90,$$
   which gives $$x+y=5,$$
   $$x+z=6$$ and
   $$y+z=3,$$
   which gives $x+y+z=7$ and
   $$(x,y,z)=(4,1,2)$$ and $$x^2+y^2+z^2=21.$$

The second case for you.

Comment: @Akshay Singh You are welcome!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg We can call it "Hopeful restriction of domain" tecnique  :))

Comment: from $(x+y)(x+z)=30, (x+y)(y+z)=15,(x+z)(z+y)=18$ you could have set $a=x+y,b=x+z,c=y+z$ to get $ab=30,ac=15,bc=18$ which have solutions $a=\pm 5;\;b=\pm 6;\;c=\pm 3$ and finally solve for $x,y,z$

Comment: @Raffaele Yes of course! I think our solutions are the same.